# Is it possible to add a web user control to a class library?

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I'm looking at building some web user controls with an eye toward re-use, but I can't seem to add a Web User Control in my class library in VS2008. Is there a way to work around this problem, or is there a better approach to creating reusable controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create either **Web User Controls** or **Web Custom Controls** that encapsulate the functionality you need. The main difference between the two controls lies in ease of creation vs. ease of use at design time.

You should maybe consider creating a Web Custom Control library. There is a [walkthrough for creating a web custom control using the Web Control Library template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728786(VS.71).aspx).

According to the MSDN article "[Recommendations for Web User Controls vs. Web Custom Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa651710(VS.71).aspx)" these are the differences between the two types of controls:

> **Web user controls** are easy to make,
>   but they can be less convenient to use
>   in advanced scenarios. You develop Web
>   user controls almost exactly the same
>   way that you develop Web Forms pages.
>   Like Web Forms, user controls can be
>   created in the visual designer, they
>   can be written with code separated
>   from the HTML, and they can handle
>   execution events.
>
> However, because Web
>   user controls are compiled dynamically
>   at run time they cannot be added to
>   the Toolbox, and they are represented
>   by a simple placeholder glyph when
>   added to a page. This makes Web user
>   controls harder to use if you are
>   accustomed to full Visual Studio .NET
>   design-time support, including the
>   Properties window and Design view
>   previews.
>
> Also, the only way to share
>   the user control between applications
>   is to put a separate copy in each
>   application, which takes more
>   maintenance if you make changes to the
>   control.
>
> **Web custom controls** are compiled code,
>   which makes them easier to use but
>   more difficult to create; Web custom
>   controls must be authored in code.
>   Once you have created the control,
>   however, you can add it to the Toolbox
>   and display it in a visual designer
>   with full Properties window support
>   and all the other design-time features
>   of ASP.NET server controls.
>
> In addition, you can install a single
>   copy of the Web custom control in the
>   global assembly cache and share it
>   between applications, which makes
>   maintenance easier. For more
>   information see global assembly cache.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps (from [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/02/07/addingwebusercontroltoaclasslibraryinvs.net2005.aspx) by Phil Haacked):

1. Close VS.NET 2005.
2. Open the directory C**:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Web\WebNewFileItems\CSharp** (assuming a default installation of VS.NET).
3. Open the **CSharpItems.vsdir** file in Notepad. Select the text and copy it to the clipboard.
4. Now open up the file **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC#\CSharpProjectItems\CSharpItems.vsdir** and paste the contents of the clipboard underneath the existing text.
5. Now copy the contents of **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Web\WebNewFileItems\CSharp** (excluding CSharpItems.vsdir) into the folder **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC#\CSharpProjectItems**.

Now “Web User Control” should be an option when you select Add | New Item.

*Reference: http://haacked.com/archive/2006/02/07/addingwebusercontroltoaclasslibraryinvs.net2005.aspx*

Comment: I did try that with VS2010 ..but it partially worked ..any idea how to achieve this is VS2010

Answer (score 1):

As platte's link mentions, if you're going for reuse then Web User Controls aren't very good. The ascx file has to be manually copied to every project you want to use them in, or you have to hack your way around that.

It's better to use System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl which is what you get when you add an "ASP.NET Server Control". These are designed for reuse. If one of the existing framework controls fits the bill for the most part and you just need to extend the functionality of it, then add an "ASP.NET Server Control" and change it to inherit from Panel or Menu or whatever.

If you're still determined to get reusable Web User Controls to work, then [this article by The Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/28/423888.aspx) should set you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project template called "ASP.NET Server Control" that I assume you can use...

--larsw

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything in a class library.

1. Add reference to System.Web
2. Create your new Control class that inherits
   from WebControl or HtmlControl or
   whatever.

That's it. You now have a reusable control for ASP.NET.

You could do some special things like add attributes to your class and properties, but they are really not needed.

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[Category("...")]
[DefaultValue("")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could using virtual path providers but you you should consider whether it really is worth your wile. Consider this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP2UserControlLibrary.aspx) on the subject.